# Grey background after using Filter css on IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, filter, ie-developer-tools

I add  a css rule

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)
```

to an text element . It rotates as I expected. However, I found that the background - color will change to grey. I tried changing the **background-color** to **none** it still not working, any fix for this?  Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
zoom:1;
position:relative
```